# ClassCastException in HashSet.put()

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset, classcastexception

In seemingly simple code - as far as it relates to the problem - such as this:

```java
private final HashSet<ValueType> set = new HashSet<>();
...
void doIt(ByteBuffer b) {
  set.add(new ValueType(b));
}
```

I got this ClassCastException in prod, out of the blue:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap$Node cannot be cast to class java.util.HashMap$TreeNode (java.util.HashMap$Node and java.util.HashMap$TreeNode are
> in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

```
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$TreeNode.moveRootToFront(HashMap.java:1882) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$TreeNode.treeify(HashMap.java:1998) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.treeifyBin(HashMap.java:767) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:639) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:na]
...
```

The Java VM used is Corretto-11.0.3.7.1 (11.0.3+7-LTS) on Linux.

I wonder if that is a bug in HashSet/HashMap?

The only other possibility I can imagine is that it is due to me adding elements to the hash set from different threads, which I <strike>don't think I'm doing, but I will verify now.</strike> am not doing. All calls to doIt() are inside `x.lock()` or `if (x.tryLock())` blocks, where `x` is a final `ReentrantLock`. So yes, multi-threaded, but properly synchronized.

Although I definitely agree with user207421 and Stephen C in the comments that it would be unlikely for such a bug to still be in HashMap...

**Edit** After having cleared the multi-threading question, my focus is now on the `ValueType`. It is supposed not to change, but it is theoretically possible. Will need to verify if it can indeed get changed in practice. The following snippet shows that class, stripped of all irrelevant details. So `b` could potentially get changed outside of `ValueType`, after having passed into its constructor, which would be bad, as it would affect `hashCode()` and `equals`.

```java
public class ValueType {
    private final ByteBuffer b;
    private int hash;

    ValueType(ByteBuffer b) {
        this.b = b.duplicate();
        this.b.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || ValueType.class != o.getClass()) return false;

        ValueType that = (ValueType) o;
        return b.equals(that.b);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int h = hash;
        if (h == 0) {
            final int pos = b.position(); // will actually always be 0
            for (int i = b.limit() - 1; i >= pos; i--)
                h = 31 * h + b.get(i);
            hash = h;
        }
        return h;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try synchronizing the `doIt()` method and see if if keeps happening. It won't.

Comment: @user207421 In other words, you are sure it is due to multi-threaded access. Of course this happened once in prod, after many months without issues, and it only happened in one of the 2 redundant instances which process the exact same data, so it seems hard to reproduce in the first place, without changing the code. But I'm digging into the multi-threaded or not question right now.

Comment: *"The only other possibility I can imagine is that it is due to me adding elements to the hash set from different threads, which I don't think I'm doing, but I will verify now."* - I think you will find that that is the real problem.  The `HashMap` class is not thread-safe. (But take a careful look at the `HashMap` source code.  I doubt that there is any way that a single-threaded application could trigger this scenario; i.e. confusion over whether a "bucket" contains `Node` or `TreeNode` objects.   That a bug of that nature could still be in the codebase stretches credibility.)

Comment: @StephenC I tend to strongly agree, however after checking, it looks like all access to that HashSet is inside a `lock()` (or `tryLock()`) block done on the same `ReentrantLock` instance. I must be missing something.

Comment: Yes, in other words I am sure. Millions of people have been executing this class for 26 years without such a bug being reported, or rather if it had been reported it would certainly have been fixed pronto. Very unlikely to even escape Java QQ.

Comment: To be accurate, the `HashMap` code was completely rewritten in Java 8.  But the code has still been around for a **long time**.  And my point was that if this is not a thread-safety issue, then the (hypothethical) bug in `HashMap` needs to be pretty blatant.